# CUDA: why is a particular memo copy operation always costs 10 times more than other similar ones

Tags: c++, cuda, nsight

I believe the following code carry out a typical

- copy to device
- call kernel
- copy back to host

workflow.

1. What I found that was very strange is when I used Trace Application option by the NSight Profiler, in the report, with 'stack trace' turned on, I found out that the most expensive operation is the line in bold, and just that line, while other memoCopy operation cost almost only as 10% or less of this memoCopy operation.

   Is this because it is the first line after calling the kernel hence the profiler somehow included the cost of some synchronization into the cost of this particular memoCopy operation?
2. For the problem like the one I'm working on, which requires very frequent synchronization and 'returning' the result to host, can anyone offer some general advice on the best practice? I was thinking in particularly about two options, which I am not so sure if will eventually help

   - use 'zero-copy' memory, (CUDA by Example 11.2)
   - create my how synchronization using atomic operations

{

```
int numP = p_psPtr->P.size();
int numL = p_psPtr->L.size();

// Out partition is in Unit of the Number of Particles
int block_dim = BLOCK_DIM_X;
int grid_dim = numP/block_dim + (numP%block_dim == 0 ? 0:1);

vector<Particle> pVec(p_psPtr->P.begin(), p_psPtr->P.end());
Particle *d_part_arr = 0;
Particle *part_arr = pVec.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_part_arr, numP * sizeof(Particle)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_part_arr, part_arr, numP * sizeof(Particle), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

vector<SpringLink> lVec(p_psPtr->L.begin(), p_psPtr->L.end());
SpringLink *d_link_arr = 0;
SpringLink *link_arr = lVec.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_link_arr, numL * sizeof(SpringLink)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_link_arr, link_arr, numL * sizeof(SpringLink), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

Point3D *d_oriPos_arr = 0;
Point3D *oriPos_arr = p_originalPos.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_oriPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_oriPos_arr, oriPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

Vector3D *d_oriVel_arr = 0;
Vector3D *oriVel_arr = p_originalVel.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_oriVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_oriVel_arr, oriVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

Point3D *d_updPos_arr = 0;
Point3D *updPos_arr = p_updatedPos.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_updPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_updPos_arr, updPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

Vector3D *d_updVel_arr = 0;
Vector3D *updVel_arr = p_updatedVel.data(); 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_updVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_updVel_arr, updVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

int *d_converged_arr = 0;
int *converged_arr = &p_converged[0]; 
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_converged_arr, numP * sizeof(int)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_converged_arr, converged_arr, numP * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

// Run the function on the device
handleParticleKernel<<<grid_dim, block_dim>>>(d_part_arr, d_link_arr, numP,
    d_oriPos_arr, d_oriVel_arr, d_updPos_arr, d_updVel_arr, 
    d_converged_arr, p_innerLoopIdx, p_dt);

**HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(oriPos_arr, d_oriPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));**
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(oriVel_arr, d_oriVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(updPos_arr, d_updPos_arr, numP * sizeof(Point3D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(updVel_arr, d_updVel_arr, numP * sizeof(Vector3D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(converged_arr, d_converged_arr, numP * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

}

Comment: add a call to cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the kernel launch, and see how it affects the timing of that cudamemcpy.

Comment: @alrikai Thanks! I also intended to try that. Would you say that the expected outcome will be such that the cudaDeviceSynchronize() becomes the most expensive run time call and overall cost remains the same if not increases? If so, is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular `cudaMemcpy` call takes longer because it has wait until your kernel completes. If you add in a `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after the kernel, your perceived execution time of that `cudaMemcpy` call should be in line with all of the others. (Of course,  that additional time you're seeing will instead be spent in your `cudaDeviceSynchronize` call).

However, the time you spend in `cudaDeviceSynchronize` is somewhat of a fundamental cost that you can't really get around; if you need to use an output from your kernel, then you'll have to wait until the kernel is done executing. Since kernels launches are asynchronous, you can execute un-related statements while the kernel is running; however, in your case, the very next call is copying one of the outputs of your kernel to host memory, so you have to wait for the kernel to finish in order to get the data.

If your program permits, you can try breaking up your kernel launch and memory transfers into chunks and launching them using different streams, although the viability of this is contingent on a couple of factors (i.e. your kernel might not decompose well into independent parts). If you do go this route, the best case scenario would be like this (taken from [the CUDA Best Practices Docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#asynchronous-transfers-and-overlapping-transfers-with-computation))

[image]

This would allow you to overlap data transfers with kernel execution, which serves to hide some of the data transfer costs. You can achieve similar asynchrony with zero-copy, just be forewarned that such transfers aren't cached, so depending on your kernel access patterns, you can end up getting lower throughputs.

Comment: thanks again, so after some adjustment of my code, I saw something (apparently good for but) quite strange:

In the timeline view of the application tracking report:

Comment: (con't previous comment):

- 
the most expensive call to 'cudaMemcpy' (showing in the CUDA Runtime API row) and call to my kernel function 'kernelFunc'(in the Compute row) are running during roughly the same time period.

Comment: Of course, this seems to be an ideal behavior for me, but I wonder how that is possible - shouldn't kernel start after and finish before any memo copy if the program is written as my code? or I really need to explicitly call cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the kernel call and right before I copy the data back to host to ensure the integrity of the data?

Comment: kernels and memcpys in the same stream are serialized, you don't need explicit synchronization, it's done for you. I don't know why the profiler is showing that, but it's probably not an accurate reflection of what's going on

Comment: Does your card support concurrent copy and compute? (you can check in the deviceQuery SDK sample). For that matter, you might just want to read about concurrent copy and compute in [this section of the cuda docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#asynchronous-transfers-and-overlapping-transfers-with-computation)